# Use components from two versions of the same library (npm / Material UI in my case)

Tags: reactjs, version-control, npm, material-ui

I'm using the latest stable version of Material UI in my production React app.

I need the updated Data Tables component, which is currently in Material UI's unstable alpha branch.

I don't want to upgrade my whole app with `npm i material-ui@next` because of the numerous breaking changes.

How can I access the alpha library without upgrading my whole library?  Can I install two versions of MUI?  Can I call on the alpha API without installing it through NPM?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Installing multiple versions of a package in parallel using `npm` is not possible. The best workaround I've seen is to create a "shim" package (ex `material-ui-next` that depends on `material-ui@next`) and depend on that in your project.

Comment: thank you @Aaron -- I'm familiar with shims in the npm registry, would I have to create a new, renamed npm package, or can I do this locally?

Comment: Yes, you can [`install` a local filesystem module](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) using `npm install ./path/to/material-ui-next` or you can [use `npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link).

Comment: Hi Doa, did you find any solution to this? I am having this problem and you might have some insights on how to tackle that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47947521/npm-install-package-in-absolute-path-locally-and-package-json Thanks.

Comment: Hey @KevinGhaboosi very belated reply, but I followed Aaron's instructions above and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 18):

After some googling, found [this](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/7195). To use both versions:

```
yarn add material-ui@latest
yarn add material-ui-next@npm:material-ui@next
```

Then you can use

```
import Divider from 'material-ui-next/Divider'
```

or

```
import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider'
```

Comment: I successfully added the two versions of the library with Yarn, but after compiling I get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prepareStyles' of undefined.

Comment: @Jumpa same here. I think it's to do with the different way MuiThemeProvider is used in the two different versions. I'm trying to solve this currently - let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: there is a caveat to this solution: every time I do a `yarn upgrade`, yarn converts both material-ui versions in package.json to the `next` version. I then have to manually correct to 0.20.0, delete node_modules and yarn.lock, then run yarn again

Answer (score 2):

I created in `/packages` a folder called `material-ui-next` with only a `package.json` inside it which contains :

```
{
  "name": "material-ui-next",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "mv node_modules/material-ui/* ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "material-ui": "next"
  }
}
```

So now from the root of the project one can do `npm install packages/material-ui-next --save` then one can `createPalette = require('material-ui-next/styles/palette')` or whatever one wants to require from `material-ui` now aliased as `material-ui-next`.

Explanations : as `"material-ui": "next"` is a dependency it's will be installed in `node_modules/material-ui` so  by adding a script after the package `material-ui-next` is installed to move `node_modules/material-ui` to the root of the package we can `require('material-ui-next/WHATEVER')`

Comment: won't it also move the original `node_modules/material-ui/` folder?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question but if you're wondering if the postinstall scripts may move the module of your actual projet it isn't the case because the root folder of the script will actually %YOURPROJECTROOT%/node_modules/material-ui-next and this folder contains another node_modules with material-ui whose content is moved by the script to the top of the folder material-ui-next. Does that answer your question ?