# Material UI — using v1 and "next" version together

Tags: material-ui

I want to use released "next" components from "next" branch of Material UI with current v1 components and smoothly move legacy to "next" as next components releases through. Does old and new versions have some sort of compatibility?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use components from two versions of the same library (npm / Material UI in my case)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258202/use-components-from-two-versions-of-the-same-library-npm-material-ui-in-my-ca)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this comment in the migration guide issue:

https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/7195#issuecomment-314547601

Use yarn and add dependencies like this:

```
yarn add material-ui@latest
yarn add material-ui-next@npm:material-ui@next
```

After that you can use the current and the next components like this:

```
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton'; // v0.x
import Button from 'material-ui-next/Button'; // v1.x
```