# Error of dependencies with react-native

Tags: react-native, mobile-development

I use react-native for my school project and like the official documentation, I use the following command to create new project :

```
    create-react-native-app AwesomeProject
```

it creates a project with the latest react native package such as :

```
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "^0.45.1",
```

Now, I would like use "react-number-format" in my project but, I always have a  problem of dependencies.

```
    npm WARN react-number-format@2.0.1 requires a peer of react@^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0.0 but none was installed.

    npm WARN react-number-format@2.0.1 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0.0 but none was installed.
```

And I have an error when I try to use the library (just with import). Can Anyone help me?

NB : Anothers libraries use "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12" as dependence so I can't change it

Comment: It's just a warning, because of the -alpha.12 suffix npm doesn't recognize it stands in the ^15.0.0 condition. You can ignore it :)

Comment: ahh, of course if it is just a warning don't worry. Only need shim package if the library isn't compatible with the new versions

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to create a shim package for react-number-format.

To do it just create a new folder in your project (for example "react-number-shim"). Inside it create a package.json and add at dependences the two libraries.

I think this will do the trick, I never done one before but I know it is possible to do.

If you don't get it let me more time to make some tests.

Comment: I create the folder and like as you say. like this :

        {
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "15.6.1",
        "react-dom": "15.6.1"
    }
}

tell me if I do wrong.
What I have to do now? Did I need to import this into the primary package.json? thx

Comment: Yep thats the theory, I'm trying too. Some time ago someone posted all the steps, I'm trying to find the post.

Comment: It is requiring me a post-install scrip

Comment: Ok I found it: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258202/use-components-from-two-versions-of-the-same-library-npm-material-ui-in-my-ca) this is the post. I will do some tests