# npm install package in absolute path (Locally and package.json)

Tags: node.js, npm, material-ui

First of all, huge apology for naive question and if this sounds duplicate.

I wish to install a package, for example `material-ui`, as an external dependency under a different path like `./node_module/my-material-ui`. The problem is I don't seem to find any option to tell `npm` to do this other than `--prefix` option which actually doesn't help because it installs the package under `./node_module/my-material-ui/node_modules/material-ui`. Infact, this makes sense since it ***prefixes*** the installation path. I searched around but didn't immediately find a solution.

Now as a following question, instead of individually (and locally) installing the aforementioned package using `npm install ...`, you wish to specify where the package has to be installed in `package.json`. In other words, how one can achieve the above goal by specifying that inside `package.json`.

Thanks in advance for your help and recommendations!

Comment: why do you need it to install as a different name/path?

Comment: Hi Joe, I am using both `material-ui` and `material-ui-next`. When using components from `material-ui-next`, the internal logic calls `material-ui` instead of `material-ui-next`. This means instead of picking code from `material-ui-next`, it goes to `material-ui` and fails since it doesn't find what it's looking for. Makes sense?

Comment: Possibly related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258202/use-components-from-two-versions-of-the-same-library-npm-material-ui-in-my-ca

Comment: Good one Joe! I think I have passed thru. the issue with having both versions installed for the same project. I actually have `material-ui` installed on `node_modules/material-ui` and `material-ui-next` installed in `node_modues/material-ui-next`. Looks like the question you mentioned is talking about the same namespace collisions too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [migration guide](https://material-ui-next.com/guides/migration-v0.x#where-should-i-start-in-a-migration-) covers this scenario.

```
yarn add material-ui@latest
yarn add material-ui-next@npm:material-ui@next
```

then

```
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton'; // v0.x
import Button from 'material-ui-next/Button'; // v1.x
```

Comment: Hi Matt, looks like `yarn` does something different than `npm` because under former I don't seem to have the problem anymore.

Comment: It's mentioned in the guide I linked to - yarn provides an aliasing feature.